# How can i call phonegap functions in html

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I'm building a basic html application for mobile using jquery mobile and phonegap build. i have a button for closing the application in mobile. i got the code for closing the application.

my code is :

```
function close_app(){
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

I build my application with phonegap build . and tested it in my android phone but the code is not working for me.

Can you tell me is it possible to use phonegap functions in build phonegap.

if possible how can i do that?

Comment: 1. Has deviceready() fired yet when you invoke close_app?
2. Is the close_app executing? Check it with a console.log and Logcat.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
 alert('Device ready');
}



function closeapp(){
  navigator.app.exitApp();
}
</script>

Comment: i already added it but i dont get any response.

Comment: could you please show us how you invoke the function?

Comment: <code>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.alerts.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
alert('Device ready');
}
function closeapp(){
navigator.app.exitApp();
}
</script>
<img src="close.png" width="32" height="32" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="closeapp();"/>
</body>

Comment: there is no onClick for <img> Tag. Use jQuery and Google.

Comment: you don't see the <img src="close.png" width="32" height="32" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="closeapp();"/>  o have a onclick function here.

Comment: just because you´re using onclick in an img tag doesnt mean it exists. It DOES NOT EXIST.

Comment: Wrap the img tag in an a tag and put the onClick on that. <a href="#" onClick="closapp();"><img src="close.png" width="32" height="32" /></a>.

Comment: hello brimil01 thanks for your replay i done what you say but still it is not working. <a href="#"  onClick="closeapp();" ><img src="close.png" width="32" height="32" style="cursor:pointer;"/></a>

Comment: even i don't get the device ready message in my device

Comment: is there any documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a listener event for the closebutton and associate a function.

Create a listener like this

```
document.addEventListener("closebutton", close_app, true);
```

Then in the close_app() write this

```
function close_app() {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

It would be a good idea to update your phonegap/cordova version to the latest build and use the code provided above.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code and its working fine for me ;-

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, false);
function deviceready() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    function onBackKeyDown() {
        if (confirm("Do you want to Exit?")) {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run the code below on your PhoneGap App. You need to wait 'deviceready' event to use PhoneGap ApI. Then, you should add event listener to any elements. When 'deviceready' event does not come, please make sure whether your cordova.js is loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!--This line should be updated according to your cordova.js version-->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script>

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceready, false);

    function onDeviceready(){

        console.log('Now you can use PhoneGap APIs');

        document.getElementById('exit_button').addEventListener('click', closeThisApp, false);

            console.log('Add click event to the button and call app.exitApp');
            function closeThisApp(){
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="exit_button">Exit</button>

</body>
</html>
```